# Pycharm stopped working in remote interpreter

Tags: python, pycharm, remote-debugging

I have been using remote interpreter all the times before, but suddenly it shows failed error message: can't run python interpreter: error connecting to remote host:

I am using SFTP, and I have tried "Test SFTP connection", got success message with the same host.

I am wondering how do I see verbose message in the remote debugging connection.

I am using PyCharm 2017.2 professional.

Comment: Try upgrading to PyCharm 2017.3 EAP 4, they've enhanced and refactored remote SSH debuggers .. you might have success. https://blog.jetbrains.com/pycharm/2017/10/pycharm-2017-3-eap-4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solve the problem. There are two places to edit the same remote interpreter. One is from `Default Setting-> Project Interpreter -> Setting Icon -> More -> edit icon`, another is from `Tools -> Deployment -> Configuration`. The settings in both places need to be correct for the same remote interpreter.

For some reason, the password in my first location was cleared.